# Why can't my udev rules rename kernel device nodes after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, kernel, udev

In Ubuntu 12.04 I wrote the following udev rules to fix the `/dev` name of a USB RF remote control.

These were:

```
KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ATTRS{name}=="BTC USB Multimedia Cordless Keyboard", ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0", NAME="input/rfremote0"
KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ATTRS{name}=="BTC USB Multimedia Cordless Keyboard", ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input1", NAME="input/rfremote1"
```

This worked, on boot there was always `/dev/input/rfremote[0, 1]`

Then I upgraded to 14.04 and these stopped wotking with the following error:

```
[   15.540765] systemd-udevd[382]: NAME="input/rfremote0" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-emprex.rules:3
[   15.673842] systemd-udevd[382]: NAME="input/rfremote1" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-emprex.rules:4
```

How do I get the rules to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered elsewhere: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-there-a-way-to-change-device-names-in-dev-directory

The udev manpage says:

> NAME
>
> The name to use for a network interface. See systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism for setting the interface name. **The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.**